# Append label to * columns on SELECT

Tags: mysql, database

For one column it's simple:

```
SELECT myColumn as 'My super sweet column', yourColumn FROM myTable;
# Results in:
# +-----------------------+------------+
# | My super sweet column | yourColumn |
# +-----------------------+------------+
# |                     1 |          0 |
# +-----------------------+------------+
```

How would I achieve something like...?

```
SELECT * as 'Random_'* FROM myTable;
# To result in:
# +-----------------+-------------------+
# | Random_myColumn | Random_yourColumn |
# +-----------------+-------------------+
# |               1 |                 0 |
# +-----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hand-code it. There's no such shortcut. Anyway, it is always best to be explicit about the columns you select and their order rather than `SELECT *`.

Comment: You could use a stored procedure that dynamically generates the SQL, but that's a ton of work and kind of inflexible.

Comment: I have a solution for this, bear with me while I search for it in my old projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reasonable way to do what you want. You have to list all column names and their aliases.

Comment: I'm not downvoting your answer just yet, but you should edit/delete your answer because the problem is solvable. I don't understand the upvotes though.

Comment: @LajosArpad I mean no reasonable way.

Comment: If the scheme of those tables are changed frequently or tables are generated then the "no reasonable way" is the most reasonable, because we don't want to change the source code every now and then.

Comment: @LajosArpad If the scheme is changed frequently that means the model is weak for the most of cases. The most reasonable solution is to make all names manipulations in the software which runs the query (php, python, c++, whatever he has).

Comment: Not necessarily, if tables are generated the model is not necessarily weak, it's just dynamic. Believe me, there are a lot of cases in which we need this type of handling. For example I've made a scientific research which was agnostic of the database model, let's say that what I was doing works at any database. You are installing my project and it finds whatever (that's my secret until it will be published) in your database. So I think we should believe the op that he/she has a valid reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
show columns from yourTable;
```

Each row of the result set of this query represents a column and the first column of this result set is the column name. Knowing this you can sequentially process the columns of the table and get the names of the columns of the table. Using the names of the columns of the table you can generate your query.

If you want to generate this kind of query for all the tables run

```
show tables;
```

And process each table running the show columns from yourTable command (replacing yourTable with the table name).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the [information schema tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-schema.html) to create a query that manually renames each column:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(
         '`',        REPLACE('`', '``', COLUMN_NAME), '` AS
          `Random_', REPLACE('`', '``', COLUMN_NAME), '`'
       ), ' FROM myTable') INTO @qry
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDB' AND TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';
```

At this point, `@qry` contains the string (except for whitespace which I've added for readability):

```
SELECT `myColumn`   AS `Random_myColumn`,
       `yourColumn` AS `Random_yourColumn`
FROM   myTable
```

Which can then be [prepared](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for execution:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
```

Executed:

```
EXECUTE stmt;
```

And finally deallocated:

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, the fact that you are seeking to do this *suggests* that the schema of `myTable` is not known to your application (i.e. that it is dynamic).  That is *usually* bad practice, and potentially indicates that you need to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure.

Moreover, I don't quite understand why the names of the columns in your resultset matter to you greatly as your application can refer to them however it wishes?

Comment: The actual query I need this for consists of 7 joins, where 3 of the joins point to the same table, but joins different row. And, when in PHP I'm fetching the join-full query, column names from the 3 tables collapse into a single array key, but I need all of them. *I hope I've made myself clear*

Comment: @psycketom: You can qualify column references in PHP with the table name.